# How to populate a list in android

Tags: android, listview, tablerow

The page layout is like:
An header image first
a table or list with one record each line
for each record, it has an image and 2 text view

how can I design this layout and populate the data dynamically, e.g. via web download or an data file(xml/text format)?

I can't figure out how the binding works and should I use a table layout with table row or just list view with some customizations?

Comment: What I want is like the sample in this post but with another header image: http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The page layout is... it has an image and 2 text view.

Elaborating on jitendra's answer: Yes, a ListView seems ideal for this set up. A TableView is doable, but is really more ideal for a rows/columns structure and that does not sound like what you need.

> How can I design this layout ... ?

You would use the android XML to name and style the elements. The best practice is to make a layout file for the screen containing the list itself. Make a second layout file to house a generic record. In other words, you typically design the record separately from the list and its containers. There are several great tutorial on Layouts on the Android Developer's website.

> How can I... populate the data dynamically?

There are two parts to this question. First, in code you will need an Adapter of some kind to convert the Data to the actual Views. The ListView will be linked to the Adapter. The Adapter will inflate the Layout XML that you create for the Record. Different Adapters have different guidelines for customizing the Views. As mentioned by Paresh, a BaseAdapter is a great class, but you really should look at the different Adapters provided and see if they already meet your need.

Second, to get the data...1) from the web depends a lot on your web server and how it distributes data. Without more information, you are unlikely to get any solid answers. We can only make recommendations. 2) If you are going via a data file, things change considerably. You can make an Array of objects from a custom Class designed around your data. If you need Sorting, a Tree might be better. If each record has a unique key, a Set or List might do you well. Based on your question, I find myself assuming that you are unfamiliar with Android development, so I would recommend a datafile loaded into an Array with an `ArrayAdapter`. This will at least help you get a little more familiar with your own project and how it relates to the Android environment.

> I can't figure out how the binding works

Unfortunately, it depends on your View and its Adapter. A `CursorAdapter` does most of its data binding in the `bindView()` method of the Adapter, but inflates the View in the `getView()` method. A `BaseAdapter` does this in the `onView()` method. If you need to get more familiar with Adapters and their capabilities, read the [Android Developer Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html). They have great samples and code. Also, do a search there for "custom adapter" and you will be linked to a **ton** of other tutorials.

At this point, I recommend strongly, two actions for you. 1) Make a few decisions. Either you get the data from the web ***or*** a data file. If you want to do the other later, great. Get a handle on one, that way we can help you more effectively. 2) Use both Google and Android Developer Resources search functionality with the phrases that define your project. If you add the word tutorial or example, you'll be sure to find plenty to help you make those decisions so that we can tailor a solution that meets your needs.

Hope this helps!

FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is going to be a broad question because you are asking about to **fetch data from web** and also **need to customize the listview** to display data.

1. **To fetch data from Web:** You haven't mentioned whether it is SOAP or RESTful webservice? Also what you will receive in response i.e. XML or JSON? For best, i would suggest RESTful with JSON.
2. **To customize ListView:** I can give you answer for customizing ListView, for that you can create a custom adapter class by extending BaseAdapter, implement the onView() method with inflation of custom row layout file (1 ImageView + 2 TextViews), check this: [**`Android custom adapter for ListView`**](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=android+custom+adapter+listview)

Comment: That's useful information. I got my solution working with Custom Adapter. and I think for fetching data from web, WCF is another option right? XML is easier for me to store the data and integrate with BizTalk

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements ListView would be good, and you would need to use adapter to bind data with view.
Please read about listview and adapter to implement these.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/img_list_background_repeater"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >   

<TextView  
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/empty_category"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No one will give you all java class and xml both.

You frame a xml. Then using adapter try to implent data to the list view.

If then you have any problem, provide your code. Then that can be solved.

Comment: I am trying to get idea first, don't want to make the wrong decision at the beginning.